# How to calculate this Frechet derivative

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $F:C^1(\Omega, [0,T]) \to C^1(\Omega, [0,T])$ with $$F(u) = u_t - f(x, t, u, u_x).$$

How do I calculate the Frechet derivative of $F$ at the point $w = f(x,t, 0, 0)t$?

It should be $$F'(w, v) = v_t - \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\bigg|_{w}v - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\bigg|_{w}v_x$$
apparently.

Maybe another day I can do this but forming the difference and then considering another difference to get out the partial derivative is confusing me!

Thanks

Comment: do you want to find the expression for the derivative or show that the Frechet derivative exists?

Comment: @Thomas I want to find the expression.

Comment: You can just differentiate formally. $u\mapsto u_t$ is linear, hence $D_v(u\mapsto u_t)= v_t$. For the $f$ -term you use the chain rule, only the third ($z$) argument depends (formally) on $u$.

Comment: sorry but I got the expression for what the derivative should be wrong. I edited it.

Comment: that proves my comment to be wrong ;-), but your result is correct, you have to look at $(F(u+sv)-F(u))/s$, which involves $x$-derivatives. Nonetheless, if you just want the result, you only need to take directional derivatives, that is, calculate $\frac{d}{d s}F(w+sv)|_{s=0}$

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I was a bit confused about how to do it formally (as in satisfying the definition on the wikipedia article) but I'll have another go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the result and already do know that the functional is Frechet differentiable (or just don't care, which is not a good attitude ;-) you only have to calculate the directional derivative
$$\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}F(w+sv) = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}\left\{(w+sv)_t - f(x,t,(w+sv), (w+sv)_x)\right\} = v_t - f_zv -f_p v_x$$
(assuming $f=f(x,t,z,p)$). This reduces the question to a one dimensional differentiation task.

Comment: Thanks. (for some reason I kept thinking you said small $f$ in the comment above.)

I see you've assumed $F$ is Frechet differentiable and hence Gateaux differentiable and calculated the directional derivative. But if you didn't know if it was Frechet differentiable how would you do it? (I do care!)